# Vaadin - Connection lost

Tags: vaadin, vaadin20

I recognized that some days I will receive a "connection lost" after reloading the current page (`UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload()`). This was not the case some weeks ago. Does it belong together to a new vaadin version? I get the same error after restarting my Spring Boot application and the client tried to reconnect.

[image: Connection lost]

Comment: Did you update something (e.g. the Vaadin version) within the project between it working and not? Was anything updated outside of the project (e.g. a new proxy)? Is this something that happens to you locally or in production?

Comment: I changed the version from 19.0.7 to 20.0.3. I tried it again with 19.0.7 and it works perfectly. Currently I have only a local environment and no production.

Comment: If memory serves 19 -> 20 upgrade is a bit trickier than most, so probably that's the problem alright. Can't really say from this alone what might be the specific problem point in your application, though.

Comment: If I understand you right there were some bigger changes from 19 to 20? Do you have an idea when I receive "connection lost"?

Comment: No, but someone else might if you manage to debug it a little further and include the details. 'Connection lost' is a very generic error, knowing which part of the connection logic fails could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately  I have no idea where to start to debug. Do oyu have a good start point? I'm not the expert regarding Vaadin...